# Pushing a struct datatype into a vector

Tags: c++, vector, data-structures, ogre3d

My structure is of the type

```
     struct SegData
      {
          Ogre::Vector3 startPt;
          Ogre::Vector3 endPt;
          float r,g,b;
          float velBeg , velEnd;
      };

    SegData seg;
```

I have a vector

```
    std::vector< SegData> temp;
```

I am trying to push back data of type SegData into my vector temp.

```
            seg.startPt = Ogre::Vector3(0,0,0);
            seg.endPt = Ogre::Vector3(1,1,1);
            seg.r = 1;
            seg.g = 1;
            seg.b = 1;

            temp.push_back(SegData());
            temp.push_back(seg);
```

I am unable to push back the element seg in the vector temp and it results in a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

Can someone please help me out here. I don't get what is going on.

**EDIT**

I restarted my laptop and segfault disappeared. But I get weird array sizes. I am posting the code below:

```
    SegData seg;
    std::vector< SegData> temp;
    zeroVec = Ogre::Vector3(0,0,0);

    posStart = Ogre::Vector3(msg->segments[j].S.position.x,msg->segments[j].S.position.y,
            msg->segments[j].S.position.z);
    posEnd = Ogre::Vector3(msg->segments[j].line.E.position.x,msg->segments[j].line.E.position.y,
            msg->segments[j].line.E.position.z);
//This is a pointer of class rviz::Line that helps plot line
    lineVisual->setPoints(posStart,posEnd);

posLeft = posStart;

    //Loop for pushing in the segData into Vector
    if(posStart!= zeroVec && posEnd!= zeroVec)
    {
        float dist = posStart.distance(posEnd);
        if (dist<1) dist = 1.0;

        if (segVec.size() == 0 || flag<id)
        {
            ROS_INFO_STREAM("INSERTING NEW ELEMENT FOR ID"<<id);  //id is passed on to this function
            segVec.push_back(std::vector<SegData> ());
            flag = id;
        }

        for(float i = 1.0; i<= int(dist); i++)
        {

            posRight.x = posStart.x+ (posEnd.x - posStart.x)*(i/dist);
            posRight.y = posStart.y+ (posEnd.y - posStart.y)*(i/dist);
            posRight.z = 0;


            posLeft = posRight;
            seg.startPt = posLeft;
            seg.endPt = posRight;
            seg.r = 1;
            seg.g = 1;
            seg.b = 1;

            temp.push_back(SegData());

            ROS_INFO_STREAM( "pushing inside temp of size  "<<temp.size());
            temp.push_back(seg);


            ROS_INFO_STREAM( "SIZE OF SEGVEC AT ID: "<<id<<" IS:  "<<segVec[id].size());
        }


        segVec.push_back(temp);
```

**Output:**

```
PROCESS MESSAGE
[ INFO] [1470169803.527734377]: INSERTING NEW ELEMENT FOR ID0
[ INFO] [1470169803.528113954]: pushing inside temp of size  1
[ INFO] [1470169803.528180252]: SIZE OF SEGVEC AT ID: 0 IS:  0
[ INFO] [1470169803.528206653]: pushing inside temp of size  3
[ INFO] [1470169803.528227194]: SIZE OF SEGVEC AT ID: 0 IS:  0
[ INFO] [1470169803.528250226]: pushing inside temp of size  5
[ INFO] [1470169803.528270518]: SIZE OF SEGVEC AT ID: 0 IS:  0
//For the next ID
 PROCESS MESSAGE
[ INFO] [1470169810.320975693]: INSERTING NEW ELEMENT FOR ID1
[ INFO] [1470169810.321037171]: pushing inside temp of size  1
[ INFO] [1470169810.321063642]: SIZE OF SEGVEC AT ID: 1 IS:  5030930206624027720
[ INFO] [1470169810.321093659]: pushing inside temp of size  3
[ INFO] [1470169810.321117828]: SIZE OF SEGVEC AT ID: 1 IS:  5030930206624027720
[ INFO] [1470169810.321141908]: pushing inside temp of size  5
```

Why is my vector size rapidly expanding?

Comment: Are you sure that it's not `temp.push_back(SegData());` that is causing the issue?

Comment: I am not sure. I thought that was how we should push a new struct element. Is that wrong?

Comment: Comment out that line and see if the segmentation fault still occurs, there might be an issue with default construction of `Ogre::Vector3` objects but I'm not sure as I don't know what they are.

Comment: You don't appear to initialize velBeg and velEnd.

Comment: @DavidThomas. But that should not be enough to cause a segfault here.

Comment: the seg fault is due to something you aren't showing us

Comment: Is `seg` a global variable or a local variable?

Comment: Why would you want to first push a default constructed `SegData` and then the one you carefully put values into. What's the point of that?

Comment: If floats are filled with uninit data, they can cause faults on some processors...  If seg is a global variable, then it will be zero-initialized.  If it's a local (stack) variable it will contain uninit floats for velXxx.  With the sparse info we have we are groping in the dark.   Someone needs to port the proverbial... time to use a debugger comment.

Comment: @ArchbishopOfBanterbury: yes, everything else in SegData is POD, which should default construct.

Comment: Has the alignment been modified during compilation?

Comment: What OS and CPU are you running on?

Comment: Ogre is an open source graphics rendering engine.  Vector3 just contains three doubles.

Comment: Based on the above I'd say you have heap or stack corruption somewhere else (not shown in the above code). You should create a [MCVE] and see if you can get it to happen.

Comment: it's Ogre3D library, and Vector3 doesn't have declared copy constructor. Maybe, this is a reason
http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.9/class_ogre_1_1_vector3.html

Comment: So the [Ogre::Vector3 class](https://bitbucket.org/sinbad/ogre/src/fbd4d24964b28d74f50ceab681181e2a7dabb593/OgreMain/include/OgreVector3.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) declares its private data as `Real x, y, z;` (Real is a typedef for double) It has an operator that will cast a Vector3 to a Real* and then access this memory as a double[].  I believe this is UB. Can you assume the `Real x,y,z;` will not have padding for alignment? (This cast operator combined with a Real* constructor is why they don't have a copy ctor.)

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. Kindly check out the "EDIT" section above. I don't have segfault any more, but my vector sizes are too big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big size value is so weird, it's got to be some garbage value, not the real size.

My first guess is maybe **the data type of the library you are using (OGRE) is doing it's own customized memory management**, for instance the type `Ogre::Vector3` may require some specific memory alignment condition (for performance consideration, or for vectorization purpose etc.). `std::vector<SegData>` uses the STL's default allocator, and that may not play well with the required alignment condition.

Just out of curiosity, I searched a little bit and found [this post](http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=46951). So basically you could try to pass the `STLAllocator<GeneralAllocPolicy>` as the second template argument (**which specifies the type of customized allocator**) to std::vector. This may worth a try, just declare you vector as:

```
std::vector<SegData, STLAllocator<SegData,GeneralAllocPolicy> > temp;
```

(where in the original post, I think they forgot the second `SegData` template argument). If it does not work, you may need to check the library documentation page (f.e. [this one](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/1.7/_ogre_prerequisites_8h_source.html)) to see if there should be other allocators or it was some other issue.

Also note that, this is quite a common issue: many libraries chose to use their own memory management strategy, either due to performance optimization, or simply due to alignment constraint. For instance, the **Eigen** (a C++ linear algebra library) library's fixed-size vector must be accompanied with it's `aligned_allocator` for proper alignment (see [here](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStlContainers.html) if you're interested in some more detail).

Hope this can help you!